# Investment code in Java

Tags: java

I have a project where I have to write a program that prompts the user for an initial investment amount and a goal investment amount and calculate how many years it will take to grow from the initial amount to the goal amount with a fixed interest rate (ie: 5 %). (use the WHILE loop). Print out the results from each year. For example, if you chose to invest $1,000 for 5 years:
    Year 1      1005
    Year 2      1011
   Etc:

**I was able to compile the java program but I was only able to prompt the user for an initial investment and goal investment with a 5% interest. The output was incorrect. What am I doing incorrect? Here is my code.**

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Investment_Calculator {//main
public static void main(String[] args) {//begins body

double principal = 1;//initial amount investing
double interest = 1;
double rate = 0.05;//the fixed interest amount
int years = 1;//amout of years it will take to achieve goal
double goal = 1;
double total = 1;

Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("*************************************** ");
System.out.println("* Welcome to the Investment Calculator * ");
System.out.println("*************************************** ");

System.out.println ("Enter your initial investment amount: if you want to exit enter   0.");
int inputNumber = myScanner.nextInt();
principal = inputNumber; 

if (inputNumber == 0){//if num = 0 exit class

System.exit(0);
}

System.out.println ("Enter your goal investment amount: ");
int inputNumber2 = myScanner.nextInt ();
goal = inputNumber2;

System.out.println ("The fixed interest rate is 5%");

total= principal; // start with our initial amount of money
for (; total < goal; total= (1+interest)*total);   

{   System.out.print("The number of years you must invest to meet your goal of $ ");
 System.out.print(goal);
 System.out.print(" is");   
 System.out.println(years);
 System.out.println(" years");

} 
}

}
```

Comment: Just a hint: if you indent your code properly it will be a whole lot easier to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (; total < goal; total= (1+interest)*total);
```

You have a semi-colon at the end of this loop. Remove it.

Because of that, your next set of `print` statements after for loop becomes an `unnamed block`: -

```
{   
 System.out.print("The number of years you must invest to meet your goal of $ ");
 System.out.print(goal);
 System.out.print(" is");   
 System.out.println(years);
 System.out.println(" years");

    years++;  <-- // Increment `years` here.
}
```

And those will be executed only once.

---

**UPDATE**: -

You can use the below code to get the totalInterest for each year and the final output

```
int years = 1;
while (principal <= goal) {
    double totalInterest = principal * rate * years / 100.0;
    principal = principal + totalInterest;

    System.out.println("Interest amount for year: " + years + 
                       " = " + totalInterest);

    years++;
}

System.out.print("The number of years you must invest to meet your goal of $ ");
System.out.print(goal);
System.out.print(" is");   
System.out.println(years);
System.out.println(" years");
```

Comment: Ok I removed the semi-colon. The math is still not adding up. Output is this. 

*************************************** 
* Welcome to the Investment Calculator * 
*************************************** 
Enter your initial investment amount: if you want to exit enter 0.
1000
Enter your goal investment amount: 
5000
The fixed interest rate is 5%
The number of years you must invest to meet your goal of $ 5000.0 is1
 years
The number of years you must invest to meet your goal of $ 5000.0 is1
 years
The number of years you must invest to meet your goal of $ 5000.0 is1
 years

Process completed.

Comment: @user1743771. That's because you are not changing your `goal` and `years` inside the loop.

Comment: @user1743771. What is your expected output?

Comment: My expected output would be if I invest an initial amount of 1000 at 5% interest rate how many years it would take for me to obtain 5000.

Comment: Increment your `years` inside your for loop, after all the print statement: - `years++`

Comment: @user1743771 that's 100 years?

Comment: Ok I updated the code and it is counting from 0 to 33. What I need now is for each of those years to say what the interest yields.

Comment: @user1743771.. For that you would have to calculate the `interest` in the loop. Are you calculating it somewhere?

Comment: I thought that was what the for line was for. Just needed some means of showing the yearly output. Sorry but I am new to java.

Comment: @user1743771. No, that for line is not calculating the `interest` any where. You need to do that in the loop. What FORMULA are you using to calculate interest?

Comment: I guess from what I researched I would have to use something like this:
double futureValue = moneyIn * Math.pow(1 + interest, year)

Comment: @user1743771. You would have to use this formula: - `totalInterest = (p * r * t / 100)` - `p` is principal, `r` is rate of interest (5 %), and `t` is year, which is from `0 to 33` in your for loop. So, use this formula inside for loop to calculate interest on each iteration.

Comment: @user1743771. And then assign the sum of `principal + totalInterest` to `principal` in the loop.

Comment: @user1743771. I have added the new code. You can check it out. And replace your for loop with the while loop. And move your `sysout` statements outside the loop.

Comment: Where am I declaring each integer because with that formula in place I have an infinite loop of years 0 and interest 0

Comment: You need to initialize your `years` with `1` before starting the loop. And in each iteration increment `years`. I missed that increment part earlier, but I added that.

Comment: @user1743771. And rest of the variables are the one you have already declared in your original code, `principal`, `rate`, `years`, and `goal`

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon at `for(; total < goal; total = (1+interest) * total);` is causing problems.

change it to :

```
for (; total < goal; total= (1+interest)*total)   
{   
 System.out.print("The number of years you must invest to meet your goal of $ ");
 System.out.print(goal);
 System.out.print(" is");   
 System.out.print(years);
 System.out.println(" years");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this with your current for- statement

```
int year = 0;
    for (; total < goal; total= ((1+rate)*total), ++year)
    {
     ...
     // whatever you were doing in for loop
    }
System.out.println (year);
```